# Users immediately logged out by devise, only on production

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authentication, debugging, devise

I'm working on a rails web app (not originally written by me). Devise is used for authentication. It works fine in the development environment. In production however, users can log in successfully, but on subsequent GET requests, they are no longer logged in and current_user is nil.

I'm not even sure how to debug this because it seems like all of the devise functionality is behind the scenes. Any suggestions as to what could cause this and what I can check?

Comment: Could it be a caching issue? If you have a reverse proxy on the production server it could be serving the same cached page to all visitors.

Comment: In that case you can check the logs if the requests are actually hitting your rails app at all. It could also be a session cookie related issue, try setting a arbitrary session value and seeing if you get it printed in the log on the next request to some other route.

Comment: The problem also occurs when I run in production mode locally, so it's not the production server but rather running the rails app in production mode.

Comment: Good, that narrows it down somewhat. Did you check the cookie issue?

Comment: did you fixed it? if yes how did you achieved that?

Answer (score 0):

The application was configured to require https and logged users out if they connected with http.